# java.io.IOException: net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: Failure] Successfully fetched the content

Tags: apache-nifi

i have Nifi Installation running on Linux, which was working fine and all of sudden FetchSFTp throwing error

my flow is List SFTP - FetchSFTp - PutSFTP. and below is the error showing in FetchSFTp process.

FetchSFTP[id=908da67c-0181-1000-1830-fdbb76da7be8] Successfully fetched the content for FlowFile[filename=cfgcampaign_2022-06-25.csv] from etl12.kw.zain.com:22/data1/dw/ftpuser/Varicent_Files/ICM_CC/cfgcampaign_2022-06-25.csv but failed to rename the remote file due to net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: Failure: java.io.IOException: net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: Failure - Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: Failure

**And from the log:**

```
2022-06-26 10:58:50,699 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP [FetchSFTP[id=908da67c-0181-1000-1830-fdbb76da7be8], StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=d139d68c-f094-45f8-982d-ab4a1abaf264,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1656230330691-548, container=default, section=548], offset=0, length=46140],offset=0,name=cfgcampaign_2022-06-25.csv,size=46140], etl12.kw.zain.com, 22, /data1/dw/ftpuser/Varicent_Files/ICM_CC/cfgcampaign_2022-06-25.csv, java.io.IOException: net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: Failure] Successfully fetched the content for {} from {}:{}{} but failed to rename the remote file due to {}
java.io.IOException: net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: Failure
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.SFTPTransfer.rename(SFTPTransfer.java:785)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFileTransfer.performCompletionStrategy(FetchFileTransfer.java:359)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFileTransfer.lambda$onTrigger$1(FetchFileTransfer.java:313)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commitAsync(StandardProcessSession.java:537)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFileTransfer.onTrigger(FetchFileTransfer.java:312)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1283)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:214)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.AbstractTimeBasedSchedulingAgent.lambda$doScheduleOnce$0(AbstractTimeBasedSchedulingAgent.java:63)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: Failure
        at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.Response.error(Response.java:140)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.Response.ensureStatusIs(Response.java:133)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.Response.ensureStatusPacketIsOK(Response.java:125)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPEngine.rename(SFTPEngine.java:250)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.rename(SFTPClient.java:124)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.rename(SFTPClient.java:119)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.SFTPTransfer.rename(SFTPTransfer.java:777)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Regards,
Ben

Comment: Error `failed to rename the remote file` sounds like some limit on your sftp server. Try to rename file manually on sftp to see an error.

Comment: Hello,it seems one file was already transferred before with same name. i changed PutSFTP to replaced and it worked.